# segmentation fault while installing angular-cli on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I've installed the newest version of node (10.10.0) on Ubuntu 18.04,

```
~$ node -v
v10.10.0
~$ npm -v
6.4.1
```

But when I put comment `ng -v` it returns

```
Command 'ng' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install ng-common
```

So that I have tried to install angular cli using `~$ sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` and then the shell returns

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I've searched Stack Overflow to find an answer, but nothing helped me. I have no idea abot this issue what to do now. Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like you are missing some libraries with the upgrade. Try `npm rebuild`

Comment: You can also try reinstalling `node` and using `nvm`